# C# creating class instance syntax?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to coding and always used "classname instancename=new classname()" to create instances but today I've found the following code which doesn't follow and won't work with this syntax. My question is what happens in the 5th line. Thank you very much.

```
private void _InsertIntoBinarySearchTree(ref Element<K> p , K key)
{
    if (p == null)
    {
        p = new Element<K>();//what happens here?
        p.key = key;
    }
    else
    {
        if (p.key.CompareTo(key) > 0)
        {
            _InsertIntoBinarySearchTree(ref p.left, key);
        }
        else if (p.key.CompareTo(key) < 0)
        {
            _InsertIntoBinarySearchTree(ref p.right, key);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the same thing you're used to...it's just a [generic type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) instead of a simple class.

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index Basically the class `Element` can have lots of different versions. You can have an `Element<int>`, `Element<string>` etc. These are all valid class names.

Comment: Element<K> p = new Element<K>();

Comment: Why doesn't work this way?

Comment: @user9630194: because `p` is the name of the method parameter.  Try a new name.. like  `Element<K> zeta = new Element<K>();`  Also note that type "`K`" will only be valid within your class (its a generic class).  Outside of a generic class you will need to specify an actual type, like `Element<int> gamma = new Element<int>();`

Comment: `Element<K> p`  is a new variable, `Element<K> p = new Element<K>();` assigns to a new variable, `p = new Element<K>();` assigns to a previously declared variable `p`.

Comment: thank you, I've never met the last one before, problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't use a type specifier for the variable `p` since you're not declaring a new variable `p`, you're *assigning* a value to an existing variable. See also:

```
int myVal;
myVal = 5;
```

Second, well, you're assigning to the variable `p`. Thus, it'll override whatever was in there before with the new value - in this case `new Element<K>()`. Technically this could be any value, but since you called `new`, it'll create a new variable and call the appropriate constructor. Don't worry about memory leaks - C# will keep track of orphaned references and clean them up for you.

Finally, since `p` is passed to your method as a [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), assigning to it will edit both the variable `p` in the local scope of the method AND the reference passed to your method from the calling scope, hence why assigning to `p` is useful as an output here.

Comment: @David  I didn't see this answer when I was writing my own.  I'll leave it because I spent about 5 minutes writing it but it's not to trump this.

Answer (score 2):

`p` if by `ref` in the method so whatever you do it is affected outside of it; meaning when you assign it with `new` the caller of the method's parameter of `p` is also reassigned.

You're stating it's an `Element<K>` type in the parameter so `p` must conform to that type.

In the method, the line in question, you reassign `p` to a `new Element<K>`  via

```
p = new Element<K>();//what happens here?
```

This is the same as `p = new Element()` in terms of how you're use to seeing it but since the `Element` type requires an generic type reference (which could be `K` or anything else) you need to also reassign it with the same type `K` passed to the method.  Because we don't know for sure what type `K` is when called.

The reason you're not using `var p =...` or `Element<K> p =..` is because `p` is already declared as that type in the parameter.  It's a `ref` parameter so you can just reassign it as mentioned.

The caller of the method may be like this as example only:

```
Element<string> p = null;
string k = "someKey";
_InsertIntoBinarySearchTree(ref p, k); //Here p goes into the method as ref; the method performs the null check and sets p as new Element<string>()
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: You're mixing up generic and anonymous types, which are two distinct things

Comment: @David You're right.  I meant generic.  I always do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice the class of the p variable is `Element<K>` from the method signature on line one. Ignoring for the moment that it's passed by ref, it's the similar to the following code.

```
Element<K> p = new Element<K>();
```

Element is a generic class of type K. K is the type of object that is being sorted. It's generic because you can choose the type of element that is being sorted. So if you were sorting cars, for example.

```
Element<Car> c = new Element<Car>();
```

The logic of what types are allowed is defined inside the definition of the generic `Element<K>` class.